# Does the threshold value of a logistic regression hypothesis has an effect on the accuracy?

Tags: logistic, accuracy, precision-recall, threshold

It is true that the threshold value of a logistic regression hypothesis has an effect on the Precision/Recall metrics.

Suppose you have trained a logistic regression classifier which is outputting $h_\theta(x)$ 
Currently, you predict $1$ if $h_\theta(x) \geq \text{threshold}$, and predict $0$ if $h_θ(x)<threshold$. 
 
Higher the threshold, the higher the precision.
Lower the threshold, the higher the recall.

This happens due to the Precision/ Recall trade-off.

But, does the threshold affect the **accuracy** at all?

Comment: Let's make 4 classifications. A and B are category 0, while C an D are category 1. Our model gives P(A=1) = 0.1, P(B=1) = 0.4, P(C=1) = 0.6, and P(D=1) = 0.9. Set the threshold to 0.5, and you get 100% accuracy. Set the threshold to 0.3, and you get 75% accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you set the threshold to $1$, then the classifier will always predict 0, which will make its accuracy $p(y = 0)$; if you set the threshold to $0$, the classifier will always predict 1, and have accuracy $p(y = 1)$; in between, it will go through various different values.